# Logging is not working. Yii Framework on Mac

Tags: macos, logging, yii

I have an application developed on Yii Framework and it was fully working on Ubuntu 11.04 on Linux. I recently had to move it to Mac Os. At the moment is mostly working but the logging function is not. It is not writing on `/protected/runtime/application.log`. I granted the right permissions to the `/runtime` folder, but still the error messages are not being logged in `application.log`.

Comment: What are you using as webserver?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd double-check that you've configured the logger to log at the appropriate level (e.g. is trace logging enabled?).

Once I did that and confirmed that my settings were correct but logging was still not happening I would then double-check the directory permissions and ownership for protected/runtime.  It's terrible practice but you could just set runtime/ to 777 to ensure that it's globally writable.  If chmodding it to 777 works then it's a permissions thing and you'll need to sort those out by ensuring that the web server (usually _www/_www on OSX) can write to the directory and that you can read the directory and the files therein.

The way I handle this on localhost is I just add my user to the _www group and `chgrp -R _www` then `chmod g+rwx` my Yii directory.  This allows both me and apache to have all access.

Answer (score 0):

have you cinfigured logging to file in your main.php:

```
'components' => array(   
      'log' => array(
        'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning, info',
            ),
       ),
```